# XF Custom Picker ItemsSource property binding not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to create a Custom Control with a label and a picker (In the future I plan to add unobtrusive validations). The below is the xaml for the control.

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             x:Class="XFTestBench.ExtendedPicker">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label x:Name="LblText" Text="{Binding LabelText}" />
            <Picker x:Name="Pkr" ItemsSource="{Binding Source}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

And here is the code behind with the bindable properties:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ExtendedPicker : ContentView
{
    BindableProperty LabelTextProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("LabelText", typeof(string), typeof(ExtendedPicker), null, BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnLabelTextChanged);
    public string LabelText
    {
        get { return GetValue(LabelTextProperty).ToString(); }
        set { SetValue(LabelTextProperty, value); }
    }
    private static void OnLabelTextChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        ((ExtendedPicker)bindable).LblText.Text = newValue?.ToString() ?? "";
    }
        BindableProperty SourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Source", typeof(IList), typeof(ExtendedPicker), default(IList), BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnSourceChanged);

        public IList Source
        {
            get { return (IList)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void OnSourceChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            ((ExtendedPicker)bindable).Pkr.ItemsSource = (IList)newValue;
        }

        public ExtendedPicker()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

The `LabelText` label binds correctly. However, I cannot get the `Source` property to bind. Here is the usage of the control.

```
<extensions:ExtendedPicker LabelText="AHOY THERE" Source="{Binding Cats}"/>
```

And here is the datasource. I have verified that the datasource is correct by using it inside a picker.

```
public IList<string> Cats { get; set; }

Cats = new List<string>
            {
                "Black Cats",
                "White Cats",
                "Red Cats",
                "Brown Cats"
            };
```

I have looked at the visual studio output window and there is nothing logged. There are no exceptions raised. I put breakpoints on the getter, setter; but only the getter is hit. The `OnSourceChanged` is also not hit. There is nothing displayed in the UI when I bind the `Source`. If I take it out, the controls are displayed.

Comment: Did you try to change List<string> to ObservableCollection<string>?

Comment: @SümeyyaTuğçeArar, I dont think the issue is the souce not being an ObservableCollection. I have the bindings working successfully on a picker

Comment: You need to show us how you use your extended picker. The issue must be there.

Comment: <extensions:ExtendedPicker LabelText="AHOY THERE" Source="{Binding Cats}"/> this is how I am using it

Comment: You can try to debug it by providing a converter in binding.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't have to create propertyChanged delegates, you just have to bind properly the properties in your Xaml to your custom binding properties in your code-behind.

Second, you are not binding those properties properly.

**Xaml**

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             x:Class="XFTestBench.ExtendedPicker"
             x:Name="RootLayout">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label x:Name="LblText" 
                   Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference RootLayout}, Path=LabelText}" />
            <Picker x:Name="Pkr" 
                   ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference RootLayout}, Path=Source}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

**Code-Behind**

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ExtendedPicker : ContentView
{
    BindableProperty LabelTextProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("LabelText", typeof(string), typeof(ExtendedPicker), null, BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public string LabelText
    {
        get { return GetValue(LabelTextProperty).ToString(); }
        set { SetValue(LabelTextProperty, value); }
    }


    BindableProperty SourceProperty = 
        BindableProperty.Create("Source", typeof(IList), typeof(ExtendedPicker), default(List), BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public IList Source
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public ExtendedPicker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but the problem is still the same. I suspected that 'Source' may be a keyword and changed that to 'Src'. But that still does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this one out. There were two issues with this.

Firstly, the `BindableProperty`(s) needed to be `public static readonly`, which is a convention I forgot, when creating this sample.

Secondly, and more importantly, I had the `BindingContext` setup wrongly. I fixed it by making the below change to the xaml:

```
<extensions:ExtendedPicker BindingContext="{x:Binding M}" LabelText="{Binding Label}" Src="{Binding Cats}" />
```

and the below to the View Model:

```
public class Model
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }

        public IList<string> Cats { get; set; }
    }

private Model _m;
public Model M { get => _m; set => SetProperty(ref _m, value); }
```

With these changes, my `ExtendedPicker` had the right context to be able to bind to both `Label` and `Cats`